# Vertical Center with Bootstrap 4 not working

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to centralize a panel using bootstrap 4, I'm using the align-items-center but I'm not having success. I already added the h-100 and still continue with the header at the top of the page. Does anyone know what could be wrong? I'm using angular 4 with bootstrap

```
<div class='container h-100'>
  <div class='row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center'>
    <div class='mx-auto col-sm-6' style="border: 2px solid red"  >
      <h3 class="text-center">Título da Aplicação</h3>
      <h4 class="text-center">Subtítulo da Aplicação</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea! The problem is that the `h-100` class adds a rule of `height: 100%`, and there's no fixed with on the `<body>` parent for the container to inherit the **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** from.

To resolve this, I'd recommend removing the `h-100` class from your `.container`, and instead manually specifying a `height` of **[`100vh`](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)**, which denotes `100%` of the *viewport height*.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center'>
    <div class='mx-auto col-sm-6' style="border: 2px solid red">
      <h3 class="text-center">Título da Aplicação</h3>
      <h4 class="text-center">Subtítulo da Aplicação</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tks, Obsidian. Worked perfectly.